# Confused about random variables and time series

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, chi-squared-test, random-variable

I have this two practical (with R) exercises for my exam:

- Using $\chi^{2}$ to test (goodness-of-fit) if fluctuations in wind speed are Gaussian.
- Calculating Lagrangian time scale for wind speed. In particular to do this I must use Lagrangian autocorrelation function that is *sample* autocorrelation function for wide-sense stationary (WSS) stochastic process (or in R `acf(x, type = "correlation")`).

To do these exercises I have 30 datasets one for every day in September 2018. Every dataset contains 1440 *measures* of wind speed from a sensor: one for each minute in that day.

**Question:** How do I have to take into consideration wind speed? In the first exercise I considered them as measure from a *continuous* random variable while in the second I considered them as time series. Is correct and possible?

## Edit

To be more exact I already solved these exercises but I reported them for further information. However I don't understand if it is possible consider a sample of 1440 measures as a continuous random variable and a time series *at the same time*. This is my doubt.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I added an edit to clarify my question.